# Mapping Temperature Transmitter Range: 4-20 mA to temperature Range: 0-100C

Tags: temperature, transmitter

I want to know as to how do you subdivide the above range 0 C To 100 C into 4 to 20 mA.? Each mA will be of what Range in degree C.

Answer (score 2):

You have 0-100 °C mapped to 4-20 mA.  That means there are 16 mA representing 100°, so each mA represents a change of 100°/16 = 6.25°.

Comment: Assuming a linear current shift to temperature change. The rise in temp itself could cause the sensor, wiring or circuit to cause unexpected shift as well.